# Get MySql column value with dynamic column name stored in other table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables in MySql. In first table I have field name list and in other I have record that column name is stored in first table.

for examlple:
first table

```
|id|name|
---------
|1|fieldname1|
|2|fieldname2|
```

second table

```
|id|fieldname1|fieldname2|
```

I have a query with INNER JOIN between this tables, Can I get value of one of the second table row with column value of first table?

Comment: What is the join condition? Initially this sounds like you're looking for a pivot table (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table) in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came across and am still looking for an answer. Here is an alternate way you could use till then.

select GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '') AS X from firsttable

and use this result in running another query

select X from secondtable